# FindAll best practices in nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have on top entity with many child entities.

Now, I want implement FindAll() method where I'm using this pattern with querying all my top entities to List. That's fine but I then get all my child objects with it, Alert: Select N+1 in nhib. profiler.

After I get all my objects I send them to FromMyDomainModel method to extract values to ViewModel I need.

```
   using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
       List<Property> data =
                   session.Query<Property>()//I don't need fetch
                   .ToList();
        transaction.Commit();
        return EntityViewModel.FromDomainModel(data);
    }
```

Maybe there is better pattern so please feel free to post.

**update: mapping code**
from mapping you can figure it my entity code

```
   public PropertyMap()
        {
            Table("Property");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Version);
            Map(x => x.Created);
            Map(x => x.Updated);
            Map(x => x.Views);
           ....
            Map(x => x.Price);            
            HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("PropertyId").Cascade.All();
        }

 public PhotoMap()
        {
            Table("Photo");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ImageMimeType).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.Property).Column("PropertyId");

        }
```

Comment: can you post the `Entity` class defn along with the mapping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the `select n+1` problem you need to set the `batch-size`

NH3.2+ sets **loading** batch-size to 20 by default so if you can upgrade then I would recommend it. See [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt) [NH-2593]

If you cannot upgrade and if are using XML mappings then do something like:-

```
<bag/set/list ... batch-size='50' ..>
...
</bag/set/list>
```

If you are not using XML mappings then please post a mapping example.

**edit based on your updated mapping**

Try this and reprofile, you should see your n+1 reduce by a magnitude of 50

```
HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("PropertyId")
  .SetAttribute("batch-size", "50").Cascade.All();
```

Also you can set this batch-size in the configuration before you build your session factory so it applies to all your collection fetching.

Comment: NH 3.x sets the **insert/update/delete** batch size to 20, not the load ones.